# Aptana editor freezes in linux

Tags: aptana

I have a problem with my Aptana dist. (version 3). When editing HTML, CSS, javascript, and whatnot, it freezes after a short while. I wander what could cause such strange behavior. To unfreeze it, I would have to click on window > Preferences (open the preferences dialog) and then close it. On clicking the editor, it opens. Has anyone had this problem and if so, how can I solve it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem once. Might have caused by the autocomplete feature. Try reinstalling using the NEWEST version of Apatana 3.  I think they have already improved their text filtering feature.